# Update array element in JAVA Spring mongo

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("55d42e3a0b21449d07f9a8a6"),
"status" : 1,
"billList" : [ 
    {
        "id" : 123,
        "status" : 1
    }, 
    {
        "id" : 234,
        "status" : 1
    },
    ......
    {
        "id" : xxx,
        "status" : 0 // only the final record has status = 0
    }

]}
```

I have many billList record and I want to update status of the final record from 0 to 1 but don't know the id of it.

```
 {
        "id" : xxx,
        "status" : 0 // only the final record has status = 0
 }
```

to

```
 {
        "id" : xxx,
        "status" : 1
 }
```

How can I use JAVA Spring to do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please have a try on below sample solution

```
     MongoClient c =  new MongoClient();

     //to get your db (Please replace "yourDB" with your db name)
     MongoDatabase db = c.getDatabase("yourDB");

     //to get your collection (Please replace "yourColl" with your collection name)
     MongoCollection<Document> yourColl = db.getCollection("yourColl");

     //search result list to be return
     List<Document> result = new ArrayList<Document>();

     //to get final record from billList 
     yourColl.find().projection(new Document("billList", new Document("$slice",-1))).into(result);

     //Based on your snippet given, assume there is only 1 document return and to get that document. You can put a loop here if there are more than 1 documents return and to be update
     Document resultToUpdate = result.get(0);

     //Update status
     yourColl.updateOne(new Document("_id",resultToUpdate.get("_id")).append("billList.id", resultToUpdate.get("billList.id")), new Document("$set",new Document("billList.$.status",1)));
```